# iOS - UIAlertView outton - otherbutton not working as it should

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I'm having trouble with my app. Problem is when I press the Cancel button on the AlertView. It doesn't show the "Cancel" text that should be appearing at my output. The Confirm and Show Password buttons are working fine, both show the NSLogs, only the cancel buttons don't. Here is my code. Please be patient with me because I'm new in Xcode.

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
     NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
    if([title isEqualToString:@"Confirm"])
    {
    UITextField *password = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"Password: %@", password.text);

        if (buttonIndex != [alertView cancelButtonIndex])
        {
             NSLog(@"cancel");
        }
        else
        {

            NSLog(@"confirm");


            entries = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            NSString *select = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM summary2 WHERE username = '%s' and pass = '%s'",[self.lbUser.text UTF8String],[password.text UTF8String]];
            sqlite3_stmt *statement;
            if (sqlite3_prepare(user, [select UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil)==SQLITE_OK)
            {
                if(sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW)
                    {
                     NSLog(@"database updated");
                    [self updatedatabase];
                    UIAlertView *alert3 = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Done" message:@"Account was updated successfully!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                    [alert3 show];
                    }
                else
                    {

                        NSLog(@"Authentication Failed!");
                        UIAlertView *alert2 = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Failed" message:@"Wrong Password! Account was not updated." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                        [alert2 show];


                    NSLog(@"fail");
                    }


            }


        }
    }
    else if([title isEqualToString:@"View Password"])
    {
        UITextField *password = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"Password: %@", password.text);

        if (buttonIndex != [alertView cancelButtonIndex])
        {
            NSLog(@"cancel");
        }
        else
        {

            NSLog(@"confirm");


            entries = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            NSString *select = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM summary2 WHERE username = '%s' and pass = '%s'",[self.lbUser.text UTF8String],[password.text UTF8String]];
            sqlite3_stmt *statement;
            if (sqlite3_prepare(user, [select UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil)==SQLITE_OK)
            {
                if(sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW)
                {
                    NSLog(@"database updated");
                    [self switchbtn];

                }
                else
                {
                     //switch1.on=YES;
                    NSLog(@"Authentication Failed!");
                    UIAlertView *alert2 = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Failed" message:@"Wrong Password! Cannot view password." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                    [alert2 show];


                    NSLog(@"fail");
                }


            }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code 
if (buttonIndex != [alertView cancelButtonIndex])
        {
             NSLog(@"cancel");
        }
when its not the cancel button you print cancel?

Comment: solved it :). I forgot I didn't add the "if([title isEqualToString:@"Cancel"])" so that when the user presses the Cancel button on the AlertView it prints "Cancel". Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your if,if-else statements you're only looking for "View Password" and "Confirm" buttons.  There is no branch in your if-statement to examine the cancel button.

Comment: oh!! I get it now! Thanks alot! so that's why it works when I remove the [title isEqualToString:@"Confirm"] condition. Thanks! Didn't notice that.